# query confusion create query without create view

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the question 
we have 3 database variable(Person, event,invited)

```
Person(pid,passwd,fname,lname), 
Event(eid, start_time,duration,description,pid)
Invited(pid,eid,response,visibility)
```

I want to make a query witch will do 
show all people each event user X create.

For example Person David create the event  with eid=  1 and 3. (2events)
and if Jany and Will invited to the eid =1 , and Mike invited to event 3
it should show

```
EID PID
1   Jany
1   will
3   mike
```

The part I confused is  Person and Event 's PID is a creater of the event 
and invited's PID is for person who invited. so its different PID value. 
so i can not just natural join them

I can solve this problem with create view mysql command but I'm writing this code 
on PHP form so I want to finish this command in one command.

what i tried is this

```
select *
from invited
where  eid
in (SELECT eid
from person natural join event
where pid = 'DD')
```

But it does not give what I expected.

How to write the code in One command without 'create view' command for this problem?

Comment: If you don't know what ON does then you really need to read up on joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT e.eid, i.pid, p.fname
  FROM event e JOIN invited i
    ON e.eid = i.eid JOIN person p
    ON i.pid = p.pid
 WHERE e.pid = ?
```

Sample output:

```
| EID | PID | FNAME |
|-----|-----|-------|
|   1 |   2 |  Jany |
|   1 |   3 |  Will |
|   3 |   4 |  Mike |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0790b/1)** demo

Recommended reading

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: is it possible to write with in, all (those kind of command?)

Comment: `ON` is a part of ANSI standard `JOIN` syntax. Although it is possible to rewrite it using a subquery instead of joins the latter usually have more chances to be optimized by MySQL.